# After adding these lines of code in my AppDelegate I get nil when unwrapping iCarousel when running

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to use [EZSwipeController](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController) as my rootViewController, I also have a [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) in my Storyboard. Before I added these lines of code (to make the EZSwipeController as my rootViewController):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = MyRootViewController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Everything is working fine, but after I added these lines of code to my `AppDelegate` xCode complains about unwrapping a nil value for my `iCarousel` variable. Is it because I'm initializing my `MyRootViewController` in `AppDelegate` and it isn't linking up with what I have in my `Storyboard`? If so how am I able to fix this?

**Edit**

The line of code that is causing the crash is in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // crashes here says that myCarousel is nil even though it is linked from the Storyboard
        myCarousel.delegate = self 
        myCarousel.dataSource = self
    }
```

I

Comment: Which line of code is actually causing the error?

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: That line of code isn't in your question. Update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: Can you show the `viewControllerData()` function in your `MyRootViewController`?

Comment: I don't have that function though..

Comment: Then how are you adding the view controllers to your EZswipeController subclass?  You need to ensure that you are instantiating them from the storyboard if you want the outlets to be connected

Comment: Oh okay so I need to create a "base" viewController and then instantiate my view controller that has the iCarousel via         `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewControllerWithCarousel")` then add it to the `viewControllerData()` function. That makes more sense I will try it now!

Comment: Yes, the swipe controller is a container view controller; you add the view controllers that you want to be able to swipe between